# Existence of periodic solutions to non-linear system of ODEs. (Polar form)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is an example problem in my lecture notes and I simply want to check whether I'm following or not.

> Consider the system \begin{align}  x'&=-y-x(x^2+y^2-3x-1)\\ 
>  y'&=x-y(x^2+y^2-3x-1) \end{align}
>
> where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. We will find an explicit expression for the
>   corresponding flow introducing polar coordinates $x=r\cos{\theta}, \
>  y=r\sin{\theta}.$
>
> \begin{align} rr'&=xx'+yy'=-(x^2+y^2)(x^2+y^2-3x-1)\\
>  &=-r^2(r^2-3r\cos{\theta}-1) \end{align}   thus
>    $r'=-r(r^2-3r\cos{\theta}-1)$. We observe that
>    $(r^2-3r\cos{\theta}-1)<0$ for $r<\epsilon$ with some $\epsilon$ small
>   enough and that $(r^2-3r\cos{\theta}-1)>0$ for $r>R$ for some $R>0$
>   large enough. Thus solutions starting in the ring shaped domain
>   $\epsilon < r < R$ do not leave it.
>
> A more precise analysis is the following: The sign of $r'$ only
>   depends on the sign of $x^2+y^2-3x-1$ having level sets as circles
>   with center in the points $(3/2,0)$. Now
>   $x^2+y^2-3x-1=(x-3/2)^2+y^2-13/4$. It means that the circle $C$ with
>   equation $(x-3/2)^2+y^2=(\sqrt{13}/2)^2$ separates domains where $r'$
>   is positive and negative. Choosing a circle with centre on the origin
>   that is contained inside the circle $C$ and another that contains $C$
>   gives an annulus domain that is positively invariant set for our
>   equation:
>
> [image]
>
> To conclude about the number of equilibrium points inside this
>   positively invariant set we derive an expression for the polar angle
>   $\theta'$:
>
> \begin{align}
>  (\tan{\theta})'&=\frac{1}{\cos^2{\theta}}\theta'=\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)'=\frac{y'x-x'y}{x^2}\\
>  &=\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2}=\frac{r^2}{r^2\cos^2{\theta}}=\frac{1}{\cos^2{\theta}}.
>  \end{align}
>
> so $\theta' = 1$ and never zero. This implies that the system has no
>   equilibrium points other than the origin, which is not in the
>   positively invariant annulus. Thus by Pioncare-Benedixsons theorem the
>   annulus $\epsilon < r < R$ must contain at least one periodic orbit.

**I have 3 questions:**

1. How can one conclude that $C$ separates ddomains where $r'$ is positive and negative without trying different values for $x$ and $y$?
2. Now, inside the black circle $C$ we have $r'<0$ and outside of it $r'>0$. To be a positively invariant set, once trajectories enter the domain, it can never leave. But if we start at the point $(-1,0)$ then $r'>0$ so eventually we will leave the circle $r=R.$ So this annular region does not make sense to me.
3. Why does $\theta'=1$ imply no equilibrium points? Is it because the angle constantly changes and for it to be an equilibrium point the angle needs to be zero at some point?

Comment: Reverse the time? Nothing was mentioned about time-reversal in the example above. I don't even know what that means in a mathematical context.

Comment: How did you get the negative sign on $rr'$? (I think this addresses @LutzL's comment?)

Comment: @copper.hat - sorry, I had a sign mistake on my system, it's edited now.

Comment: You could also directly, without returning to the coordinates, say that $$r^2−3r\cosθ−1\ge r^2-3r-1>0$$ for $r>\frac{3+\sqrt{13}}2$ and $$r^2+3r\cosθ−1\le r^2+3r-1<0$$ for $r<\frac{\sqrt{13}-3}2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to think in terms of the (equivalent) Lyapunov function
$V((x,y)) = { 1\over 2} (x^2+y^2)$.

The advantage of this function is its simplicity and geometric appeal, the disadvantage is that it does not match up exactly with the underlying dynamics in terms of
geometric interpretations. (Hence the contained and containing circles.)

Let $\phi(t) = V((x(t),y(t)))$, then we
see that
$\phi'(t) = -(x^2+y^2)((x-{3 \over 2})^2+y^2-{13 \over 4})$. In particular, with
$C=\{((x,y)| (x-{3 \over 2})^2+y^2 ={13 \over 4} \}$ we see that
$\phi'(t) \ge 0$ when $(x(t),y(t)) $ is 'inside' $C$ and $\phi'(t) \le 0$ when
'outside'.

Note that $C$ 'contains' a small circle $C_0$ centred at the origin and $\phi'(t) \ge 0$ if $(x(t),y(t)) \in C_0$.

Also, there is a large circle $C_1$ centered at the origin, that contains
$C$ and we see that $\phi'(t) \le 0$ if $(x(t),y(t)) \in C_1$.

In particular, if $A$ is the (compact) annulus 'between' $C_0,C_1$ then we see that $A$ is invariant.

To show that $A$ contains no equilibrium points, we need to show the dynamics are
not zero in $A$, since $0 \notin A$ it is sufficient to show that $\phi' \neq 0$ in $A$.