# Find periodic orbit of the system given in polar coordinates

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

> Consider the following system given in polar coordinates
>   $r'=r(r^2-5r\cos\theta - 6)$ and $\theta ' = 1$. 
>   Prove that there is a periodic orbit for the system.

I know that Poincaré-Bendixson theorem says that if there is an annular region R in which the vector field points towards the interior and there are no critical points in the region R then a periodic orbit exists in that region. I am trying to find an annulus of the form $a < r < b$ such that this annulus contains periodic orbit. Letting $r=1$ gives $r' \le 0$ and $r=6$ gives $r' \ge 0$ which is exactly opposite of what I want.

So I am not able to find values for $a, b$ for the annulus region $a < r <b$ such that $r=a$ will give $r'>0$ and $r=b$ will give $r'<0$ so that the field is pointing towards the region. Any suggestions?

Comment: I notice the locus of $r'=0$ (and $r \neq 0$) is a circle which is not centered at the origin.

Comment: Ah, yes that will make a difference. I was assuming the annulus was centered at the origin and therefore couldn't find the candidates for a and b.

Comment: That would make it $r'=r((x-2.5)^2+y^2-(3.5)^2)$ . But that would give the same problem .. for $a<r<b$, for smaller radius $a$, $r'<0$ and for bigger radius $b$, $r'>0$ which would not keep the field inside the annulus.

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3245311/418542) should help you

Comment: Yes the post you mentioned is similar to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You just want to prove the existence of a periodic orbit, it makes no difference if it is stable or unstable. So just consider the time-reversed system where the vector field points in the opposite direction at every point. Then the formulation of Poincaré-Bendixson that you have in mind applies, there is a periodic orbit, and it stays periodic if you reverse the time reversion.

Comment: Yes if we look at it from reverse time then the system allows for periodic orbit. Thanks.